# How can I configure IIS to serve a site when it is asked by ip?

Tags: iis, web, iis-6

I have a site www.example.com and example.com configured at x.x.x.190
At the moment, foo.example.com is also configured at the same ip.
In the DNS server www is a CNAME alias for example.com

How can I make it so that when a request like http://x.x.x.190 is made, the server serves the content of www.example.com, just like if the request was http://www.example.com or even http://example.com? Is changing the ip of foo.example.com to a different one enough?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Tor run > inetMgr to open up issserver

Right click on you wesite Not >> Properties >> in that go to website tab >> in that tab there is text box to set ipAddress for the website

after doing above steps you can browse your website using ip address as you want